# vulkan vkresult linker error msvc

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, vulkan

I'm trying to compile the first sample program included in vulkan, so I pasted it into a new win32 project in the vs17 rc. It is called 01-init_instance in the Samples dir. I am compiling x86.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <util_init.hpp>

#define APP_SHORT_NAME "vulkansamples_instance"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sample_info info = {};
    init_global_layer_properties(info);

    /* VULKAN_KEY_START */

    // initialize the VkApplicationInfo structure
    VkApplicationInfo app_info = {};
    app_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    app_info.pNext = NULL;
    app_info.pApplicationName = APP_SHORT_NAME;

    app_info.applicationVersion = 1;
    app_info.pEngineName = APP_SHORT_NAME;
    app_info.engineVersion = 1;
    app_info.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    // initialize the VkInstanceCreateInfo structure
    VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info = {};
    inst_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    inst_info.pNext = NULL;
    inst_info.flags = 0;
    inst_info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    inst_info.enabledExtensionCount = 0;
    inst_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = NULL;
    inst_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    inst_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = NULL;

    VkInstance inst;
    VkResult res;
    res = vkCreateInstance(&inst_info, NULL, &inst);

    if (res == VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER) {
        std::cout << "cannot find a compatible Vulkan ICD\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    else if (res) {
        std::cout << "unknown error\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    vkDestroyInstance(inst, NULL);

    /* VULKAN_KEY_END */

    return 0;
}
```

I have done the project properties like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I had this wrong and was getting linker errors for vkCreateInstance not being resolved (before adding the .lib in dependencies) now I am getting a single, different, linker error for not finding vkResult. This confuses me because I don't know how it could resolve vkcreate but not vkresult. I used all the charset settings (multi-byte, not unicode as normal) but that didn't change anything.

The error is:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "enum VkResult __cdecl init_global_layer_properties(struct sample_info &)" (?init_global_layer_properties@@YA?AW4VkResult@@AAUsample_info@@@Z) referenced in function _main  vktest  C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\vktest\vktest\Source.obj    1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The samples that come with the Vulkan SDK compile the `utils` folder into a static library, and link with that library. This is where the `init_global_layer_properties` function exists. If you don't link your sample with that library also, you will get unresolved symbols.

Comment: What would I do to remove the need for this?

Comment: Remove `#include <util_init.hpp>`, and the usage of anything inside it (eg. `init_global_layer_properties`) from your code.